# How to label graph edges with a loop?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I'm using a `for` loop to add more nodes and edges on my plot. However, when I add labels on new edges the old labels are removed. I don't know how to keep old edge-labels nor how to store the results of `labeledge`.

This is what I have got so far.

```
for r = 1: 10
    for j = 1:10
        H = addnode(P,nodeName{r}{j});
        P = addedge(H, s{r}{j}, t{r}{j}, w{r}{j});
        figure;
        hold on;
        h = plot(P);
        labeledge(h,s{r}{j},t{r}{j},labelText{r}{j})
    end
end
```

Every time in the new plot, I can only see the newest cluster of labels while old labels are gone. Ideally, I'd love to `hold on` the results of `labeledge` but `hold on` can't do this. I need to show labels in each step in the loop, thus adding another overall `labeledge` is not my ideal solution. Any hint would be appreciated.

**Edit:** All my variables are multiple cells of difference sizes in cell arrays. I use `for` loop to help to pick up vectors from cells because I don't know how to insert all the levels of information from such cell arrays of cells etc. into `addNode` function.

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop and adding all the nodes together?

Comment: I'm constructing a network like a tree. Every node has their own branches and leaves (new nodes). FOR loop helps me to raise the tree up and grow more leaves.

Comment: Why are you first assign a new node to `H` in: `H = addnode(P,nodeName{r}{j});` and then assign it back to `P` with: `P = addedge(H, s{r}{j}, t{r}{j}, w{r}{j});`? Also, I think your node names are partially overriten by this process. You should either add a list of edges, of add an Adjacency Matrix with node names.

Comment: @EBH adjacency matrix seems viable. I did have repeated node names in this process and I'll reflect repetition in the matrix. Thanks so much for your idea! I'll update with you once it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you keep plotting the graph again and again. This isn't necessary. Instead, use one loop to create the graph object (`G`), then plot it all at once, and then use another loop for labeling the graph:

```
P = graph;
for r = 1: 10
    for j = 1:10
        P = addedge(P, s{r}{j}, t{r}{j}, w{r}{j});
    end
end
h = plot(P);
for r = 1: 10
    for j = 1:10
        labeledge(h,s{r}{j},t{r}{j},labelText{r}{j})
    end
end
```

If you wish to plot your graph on every iteration, you can use `subgraph` for that:

```
for k = 1:height(P.Nodes)
    H = subgraph(P,1:k);
    figure;
    h = plot(H);
    c = 1;
    out = false;
    for r = 1: 10
        if ~out
            for j = 1:10
                if c < k
                    labeledge(h,c,labelText{r}{j})
                else
                    out = true;
                    break
                end
                c = c+1;
            end
        else
            break
        end
    end
end
```

---

Besides that, you should know that ([from Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html#buzqqbj-1)):

> For the best performance, construct graphs all at once using a single call to graph. Adding nodes or edges in a loop can be slow for large graphs.

Also, regardless of the above recommendation, for an easier manipulation of your data, you should first convert your cells to an array. If your cell array contains a different number of elements in each cell, then it is better to collapse it all to one column:

```
C = [s{:}]; % and the same for t and w
while any(cellfun(@iscell,C))
    C = vertcat(C{:});
end
C = cellfun(@(x) x(:),C,'UniformOutput', false);
S = vertcat(C{:});

Labels = [labelText{:}]; % and the same nodeName
while any(cellfun(@iscell,Labels))
    Labels = vertcat(Labels{:});
end
```

Comment: 1. You can use an [ND-array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html), not only a matrix. 2. You can represent a multileveled cell array in an ND-array with the code above, as long as all its' branches have the same shape.

Comment: @YolandaWang Great! What do you get by keeping the plotting within the loop?

Comment: Graphs in the loop are meant to test whether the network works correctly. Otherwise I'll lose the interpretation of final graph since it's too complicated to read

Comment: @YolandaWang I added another part to the answer for plotting in a loop a growing graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the 'figure;' command out of the FOR loop and try to see if this worked.

Comment: I do get more labels but not all of them (quite strange and I'm trying to figure out why). Yet without 'figure', I can't get plots in the process of the loop.

Comment: remove it and put the 'figure' before going into the FOR loop.

Comment: Also, as EBH asked you, try not to use FOR together with adding all nodes together. You can create a Vector of nodes and put them without a FOR loop (but you need also to supply data sets of the plots)

Comment: I would try to go over all the cells and pick out the relevant data to be plot (node number, next node number linked to, edge line length, etc..) and put at a table with an appropriate label - this post-processing task will be helpful later to be plotted at one plot. At this stage I would run from start to the end of the 'leaf' at certain branch and then iterate to another branch and do this again and again until all leaves will be at the plot.

Comment: maybe this should help you out: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/treeplot.html )